# Why Apache Accumulo is not running after restart?

Tags: apache, hadoop, accumulo, apache-zookeeper

I just installed Apache Accumulo. It is successfully initialized and run but after a restart when i insert start-all.sh command it stuck on waiting for Accumulo to be initialized. what's wrong here?

Comment: could you include more information please? By "restart" do you mean of the entire system?

Please include a copy of the output from the "start-all.sh" command.

Comment: after restart of my computer

Answer (score 1):

If you've restarted your computer, be sure that you have also restarted Hadoop (HDFS) and Zookeeper as well as verify they are running correctly.  They are required to be running for Accumulo.

It sounds like you might be running this locally on a single machine.  If that's the case, also verify your hadoop hdfs settings and make sure it's **not** writing its data to /tmp which will get wiped out occasionally between restarts.